# Having Trouble with Creating A Program to Measure the Distance Between Two Points in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C that calculates the shortest distance between two points here on earth (So I have to use latitude and Longitude). I am using the haversine formula to help me calculate this distance. When I wrote the code I got a bunch of errors (The main errors being C2065 undeclared identifier errors.

```
   #include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h> 

//Pi number in math 
#define pi 3.14159265358979323846
//This is the radius of the earth in KM 
#define R 3959




    int main ()
        {
        double lat1;
        double lon1; 
        double lat2; 
        double lon2;

            //The User's initial Input for Point 1
            printf("Please Enter Your Latitude anghghd Longitude foroik Point 1\n");
            scanf ("%d%d", &lat1, &lon1);
            printf("Please Enter Your Latitude and Longitude for Point 2\n");
            scanf("%d%d", &lat2, &lon2);




     double phi1; 
        if (lat1>0) 
            {
                phi1= 90-lat1;
            }
        else 
            {
                phi1=90+lat1;
            }
    double phi2;
        if (lat2>0)
            {
                phi2=90-lat2;
            }
        else 
            {
                phi2=90+lat2;
            }
    double theta1;
        if (lon1>0) 
            {
                theta1=lon1;
            }
        else 
            {
                theta1=-lon1;
            }
    double theta2;  
        if (lon2>0) 
            {
                theta2=lon2;
            }
        else 
            {
                theta2=-lon2;
            }


        double c;   
        //This is our Haversine formula to calculate the two distances between two points
        c = sin(phi1)*sin(phi2)*cos(theta1-theta2)+cos(phi1)*cos(phi2);

        int d; 
        //The shortest great circle distance between two points

        d = R*acos(c);

            printf("The distance between the two points is %d \n", d);





        return (0);
}
```

The type of errors I am getting have been C2065 undeclared Identifier which is making me believe that the if statements I am using to describe phi and theta do not work. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Please post the exact errors you are receiving.

Comment: You need to convert the angles from degrees to radians before using them in calls to `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: Incidental, but that radius you have is in miles, not kilometers.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into errors at your scanf calls. "d" corresponds to an integer not a double, use f instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing C in Visual Studio, which it sounds like you are, you'll likely have to declare all your variables at the beginning of the function (or block), because it doesn't support a modern version of C that lets you do otherwise.

In other words, you'll have to do:

```
int main(void)
{
    double lat1;
    double lon1; 
    double lat2; 
    double lon2;
    double phi1;
    double phi2;
    double theta1;
    double theta2;
```

and so on, and only then go on with your `printf()` calls and stuff.